# Minimize depth of a tree of computation

Tags: tree, binary-tree

Assume you have a binary tree of additions, where each two nodes are added together until the root is the sum of all the nodes. For example:

```
   3   2  1   3
    \ /    \ /
     5      4
      \    /
        9
```

To minimize the depth of this tree is easy: I can just run [DSW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day%E2%80%93Stout%E2%80%93Warren_algorithm) on it for instance. The reason I can do this is because the addition operator is commutative.

Now what happens if each node has a different operation? *, /, + or -? How can I find an optimal minimal depth of that computation tree? An example tree is shown below:

```
   3 * 2  1 - 3
    \ /    \ /
     6  /  -2
      \    /
        -3
```

---

What I have come up with so far is to check if each subtree consists of commutative operations only, and then I can move nodes around in that specific subtree. However, this is a very crude 1st order heuristic.

---

**Is there work detailing how we can refactor equations in such a way that we can reduce the depth of a computation graph?** This would allow for more parallelization of the code required to compute this tree.

---

Motivation: In my specific case, I am actually not doing this for software. I am building custom hardware to evaluate the arithmetic computation. So one of my optimization objectives is to reduce the hardware tree depth so that I reduce the latency of my pipeline computation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, as long as you're already visiting all the nodes of the tree trying to minimize the depth of the computation tree, is there any reason you don't then go and perform the computation? This is an interesting theoretical question, for sure, but in practice I'm wondering if it's necessary to solve it. :-)

Comment: In my specific case, I am actually not doing this for software. I am building custom hardware to evaluate the arithmetic computation. So one of my optimization objectives is to reduce the hardware tree depth so that I reduce the latency of my pipeline computation.

Comment: I think you are confusing commutativity with associativity. An operator Op is commutative if x Op y = y Op x, which would let you swap the children of a node. Tree rotation requires that the operator be associative: x Op (y Op z) = (x Op y) Op z.

Comment: Yes you are correct, for rotation associativity is required. But the case that I am describing basically checks if each subtree consists of additions ONLY, or multiplications only and can swap any of their locations.

Comment: For subtraction, you can invert signs. `a - (b - c) = (a - b) + c`. Yould change all a - b to a + (-b), balance the additions, and the turn negated addition back into subtraction. Division is trickier..